# SQLite insert list of class instances

Tags: python, sqlite

let's say I have two classes : Employee and Manager. Each employee has a name and department attributes (both strings), and each manager has a name and list of exactly two Employees.
Something like this:

```
employee_one = Employee('Jon', 'Sales')
employee_two = Employee('Jim', 'Sales')
manager_one = Manager('Tom', [employee_one, employee_two])
```

What I need to do is to store the manager's into a table (using SQLite in my case) that contain name column and employees column that will contain the list of the employees. I tried to do this straightforward:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO managers VALUES (:name, :empolyees)",
           {'name': manager_one.name,  'empolyees': manager_one.empolyees})
```

but I got an error - 'unsupported type'.

How can I preform this?

Answer (score 0):

You can register adaptaters, i think in your case it would be list type

example store list as json string

```py
import sqlite3
import json

def adapt_list(l):
    return json.dumps(l)

def test_adapt_subclass():
    """ Adapting an object from a subclass. """
    sqlite3.register_adapter(list, adapt_list)
    
    with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
        conn.execute('CREATE TABLE tab(c TEXT);')
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO tab VALUES(?);',
            ([1, 2], ))
        
        for p in conn.execute('SELECT * FROM tab;').fetchall():
            print(p[0])
            deserialized = json.loads(p[0]))
            print(deserialized)

test_adapt_subclass()
```

or create directly an adapt method for your Manager class to store it in a column

`sqlite3.register_adapter(Manager, adapt_manager)`